# Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::$admin_id

Tags: php, laravel

Why is it if the user access the admin page of a post that don't exist, like "`https://proj.test/post/manage/34`" it appears:
`Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::$admin_id`?

The error is in the boot method of the `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
 public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        $gate->define('access-management-area', function($user, $post)
        {
            return $user->id == $post->admin_id;
        });
    }
```

Comment: do a var_dump of post and you will see what is available.

Comment: If you are certain that $post has this (admin_id) property. Then you can use isset method like `isset($post->admin_id)` to check whether admid_id is NULL or not.

Comment: It shows a RedirectResponse object.

Comment: should there really be a `$gate` passed to the `boot` method? I'm scanning the Laravel docs and it's consistently using the `Gate` facade. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#writing-gates